# What is the correct syntax for IF and Loop in a MySQL script (no stored procedure)

Tags: mysql

We want to migrate data from an old MySQL-database into a new one with other structures.
So we began to write a SQL-script with some SQL statements (no stored procedure!).

Per example we are looking in one of the tables of the old database if there are entries to migrate.
If we have found entries we want to make a loop through them and insert them in the table of the new database.

But in MySQL we are getting error messages, that IF is not valid at the current position and looping with BEGIN and END does not to work in mySQL too.

Here an example for what we wanted to do:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(`AbhId`) FROM `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit` > 0) THEN
  SELECT myAbhId = min(`AbhId`) FROM `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`;

  -- Go over each myAbhId
      WHILE myAbhId > 0
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `paragraph16`.`description`
          (`languageId`,`textKey`,`text`,`isDeleted`,`changedBy`,`changeDate`)
          SELECT 1, CONCAT('Dependancy_', REPLACE(`p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`.`AbhId`, '_', '')), `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`.`Text_D`, 0, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
          FROM `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`
          WHERE `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`.`AbhId` = myAbhId;
        INSERT INTO `paragraph16`.`description`
          (`languageId`,`textKey`,`text`,`isDeleted`,`changedBy`,`changeDate`)
          SELECT 2, CONCAT('Dependancy_', REPLACE(`p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`.`AbhId`, '_', '')), `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`.`Text_E`, 0, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
          FROM `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`
          WHERE `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`.`AbhId` = myAbhId;
      END
END IF
```

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: I prefere to use another language like PHP for such a job